# Eclipse: Feature Category does not appear in update site

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

this is the url of an open source project I am working on https://code.google.com/p/mdpm/
it consists of a set of Eclipse Plugins

there is a plugin implementing the update site with a site.xml file with this content

```
<site>
   <category-def name="mdpm" label="Model Driven Project Management"/>
   <feature url="features/com.lowcoupling.mdpm.defaultFeatures_0.0.1.201401062233.jar" id="com.lowcoupling.mdpm.defaultFeatures" version="0.0.1.201401062233">
      <category name="mdpm"/>
   </feature>
</site>
```

the problem is that if I try to use the update site  http://mdpm.googlecode.com/git/com.lowcoupling.mdpm.updateSite/
(from Eclipse) the category does not appear
you have to uncheck the 'group items by category' box

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you found the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but I know that site.xml is the older format, and nowadays it's normally a category.xml .. try out something like e.g. my https://github.com/vorburger/efactory/blob/master/com.googlecode.efactory.repository/category.xml, and see if that works for you.